# Integrating CKFinder returns 404 not found

Tags: asp.net-core, ckfinder

I am trying to integrate CKFinder in ASP.NET Core.
But it returns error 404 not found.[image]

```
<script src="~/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="~/ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>

    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('Content', {
            height: 700,
            extraAllowedContent: 'article',
        });

    CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, '' );
```

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: How did you configure CKFinder in ASP.net? Did you follow docs or do you integrate it with existing app? It might be a simple misconfiguration of `connectorPath` so you should validate if CKFinder itself is available.